# 1st time math teacher 1st test feedback appreciated

Tags: secondary-education, algebra, usa, testing, test-design

I'm not a math teacher but I've stepped into the role to assist a small private school who lost their math teacher during the holidays (I'm a mechanical engineer by trade). The course is Algebra 1 (9th,10th grade) using the Pearson Common Core Algebra 1 textbook (Chapter 5 test). I wasn't given prior tests to go off of, so I've made one with the intent that it cover the essentials, but not be unnecessarily difficult. The students had some trouble keeping up in the first semester, and some have developed some math anxiety because of it, so I want this test to help them regain some confidence with the subject. Any feedback or suggestions from experienced math educators on the content, length, formatting, or difficulty are appreciated.

Link to google photos in case the images don't appear correctly in the post

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPmwbeooSRo3-RVOHKX4L6old-hEdpye9yJosSbKyJtMmKlXoN9nU7_kv1A3AC3yQ?key=Zmx2dW9UTUpyWmFwY0NjY1VGR0Vad0xXdkNwRmd3

[image: Text]
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Comment: This will depend a lot on what you've covered in class and what problems your students have already practiced on. If you've got time, I suggest giving students a similar "practice test" (same notes/calculator setup as a real test, but they can ask questions) during class a few days before so they know what to expect and you can get a good sense of what they know. Also, a few students will have trouble with subtracting a negative in the first problem, consider two positive points if you want to focus on other aspects of the problem.

Comment: @TomKern Thank you! I appreciate the feedback and I will revise the question. You make a good point on the practice test. I will do that for the next chapter. I took over half way through chap 5, so I really only have an idea about how theyve handled the 2nd half of the material for this test.

Comment: @Dan S, as a student myself, I think it would be helpful if you add on the number of marks each question is worth, that way students can prioritise which ones to do first or which ones to work longer on. Another thing I can add is that in the school I go to we are given little feedback sheets along with our test so that we can identify our strengths and weaknesses and improve accordingly. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Tommi This is the USA (Las Vegas, NV) and high school level at this school (grades 9 and 10 in the K-12 grade system). I think some schools here do cover Algebra 1 in the last year of middle school (8th grade) but this one does not.

Comment: @Arya_08 Thank you for the suggestion! I will definitely include the points for each problem on the next test. I am going to provide feedback to the students, and for those who had trouble with the material I will be working with them individually to try to assist them with their understanding of the material. Fortunately, this is a small K-12 school, so I only have 8 students in this class and can give them each individual attention as needed.

Comment: I've taught algebra 1; in general you test looks fine!
How much time do they have to complete it? My experience is at least triple, if not quadruple, the amount of time it takes me to do. If it takes me ten minutes, then my stars will finish faster than me, but the general population will take maybe 30 or 40 minutes.

Comment: @MichaelG Thank you for the feedback! I gave them 2 hours to work on the test. Even with that I still had one student that needed additional time, though that was because they froze up and made no progress for the 1st hour. Fortunately after pulling them aside and having a talk with them they were able to continue the test and ended up finishing it and scoring reasonably well.